# Connecting to DB2 via .NET DbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, db2, dbconnection

Our current DB Connection provider model relies on database connectivity to use DbConnection (System.Data) based objects.

We can connect to DB2 (*Nix * Windows) via OdbcConnection, but we would like to allow the use of native DB2 Drivers.

Is there any way to do so (either .Net framework, OpenSource or (last choice) vendor) without breaking away from our current DAL model?

Answer (score 2):

There is another method not mentioned in the article above, and that is to use **DbNetData** which simplifies database access and has the ability to connect to DB2 from .NET. The source is hosted on CodePlex below:

[DbNetData](http://dbnetdata.codeplex.com/)