# Is it Possible to smoothly develop ASP.NET MVC With DB2 (Mainframe)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, db2, mainframe

I want to develop an ASP.net MVC application with DB2 backend.
where DB2 is on Mainframe server.
I am little bit confused on this . Is it possible to access DB2(Mainframe server)  database smoothly by MVC application.
I searched on internet on this and I understand, by using three ways I can access DB2
1)  Oledb
2)  Odbc
3)  DBconnector

But then also I have some doubt like 
Network issue
Connection issue
Datatype etc issues
And how Entity framework will work against DB2(Mainframe)

So experts please guide me on this, It would be gr8 if you have any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1):

Defenetely you can use DB2 as a back-end with ASP.NET mvc application.

You can find very good asp.net mvc sample project at

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Structure your project properly.

Finally Db2 support both entity framework and direct database access using ado.net. see the following link

[Connecting to DB2 via .NET DbConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276505/connecting-to-db2-via-net-dbconnection)
[Using LINQ to Entity Framework with DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985912/using-linq-to-entity-framework-with-db2)